# Why is Intel assembler syntax dest, src?

Tags: assembly, syntax, intel

It seems to me that the logical way to order operands for asm operations is **src, dest**, since English generally prescribes **from here to there** rather than the reverse. This is **AT&T syntax**, and is rarely used (or at least, I've never had occasion to program with it). The opposite is **Intel syntax**, and is widely used. The names correspond to the companies which nominally originated them. [[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax)

Can anyone provide a reason as to why Intel syntax was accepted as the standard, and indeed why this ordering was developed and used in the first place? Am I wrong in my assumption that AT&T syntax is more natural?

Comment: I find the pointer arithmetic part of the AT&T syntax unreadable - the Intel syntax is much better at this point. Concerning the operator ordering - I'm indifferent.

Comment: Maybe there is a whole bunch of historical evidence and meaning to this, but I just want to point out that while in English and most of the languages we go "from here to there", mathematics did use "Let X be ..." for quite a while before comuters were even born. So the idea isn't entirely new, and I would argue that mathematic notation has something to do with this.

Comment: @KimitsuDesu I've seen that argument put forward, and I ask: why call the operation `mov`, short for "move"? Why not `let` or `set`, then?

Comment: @william.berg well, some assembly languages do use set instead of mov. i guess this is arbitrary. why not "settosum" instead of "add"? anyway, speaking of ordering, it may also have something to do with Polish notation. Polish/reverse polish was (and still is) quite popular in minimalistic languages, so they might have chosen one of those deliberately.

Comment: Dunno, I find Intel syntax more natural and AT&T to be somewhat obtuse...  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C-style reasoning behind the `dest, src` order: it resembles the order of the operands in an expression, for example

```
mov dest, src
```

looks like

```
dest = src
```

or

```
add dest, src
```

looks like

```
dest += src
```

(so these instructions resemble visually what they actually do.) That's probably a logical explanation.

Comment: hmm did C apper prior to this Intel assembly ordering standard?

Comment: @KimitsuDesu That doesn't actually matter (I don't know if it did) - most programming languages that follow this kind of mathematical notation convention (which is sometimes referred to as "C-style") suggest this kind of logic.

Comment: having dest on the left and src on the right goes back well beyond C or any programming language.  Very natural to have dest,src in assembly, src,dest is painful and difficult to use and comprehend because at least for alu operations it is the wrong way compared to common math notation a = b + c   add a,b,c

Answer (score 5):

> Can anyone provide a reason as to why Intel syntax was accepted as the standard

Well, it is not a standard.  There is no ISO or ECMA standard that prescribes assembly syntax.  The Intel notation is used a lot for the simple reason that it is well documented in the Intel processor manuals and Intel is a very successful company that has designed and sold a *lot* of processors.

That can't be said for AT&T.  It was a *telephone* company, never did much of anything in processor design and no longer even exists.  They made some pretty bone-headed decisions that put them out of business.  The trade name was bought by another telephone company, SBC, which then renamed itself.  The famous Bell Labs, the originator of Unix and C, and the syntax, was spun off as another company named Lucent.  No longer around either, bought by Alcatel.  Who owns Unix these days is a bit unclear, lots of law suits, but Novell seems to be ahead.

Operand order is just another little-endian vs big-endian debate.  Given a choice of two, one will be always considered wrong by the other.

Comment: Sorry for the imprecise use of terms. Intel vs. AT&T is a hotter topic amongst asm programmers than I realised: http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=19558 , though usually concerning other syntax differences. +1 for likening to other holy wars.